# How to make xdg-open to use kde-open instead of gvfs-open?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, xdg-open

I have both gnome and KDE installed in my Ubuntu, but mostly I use KDE.

When I execute:

```
xdg-open <folder_name>
```

it runs **nautilus** instead of **dolphin** (as gvfs-open also do). It seems to me that xdg-open for some reason uses gvfs-open instead of kde-open.

How to make xdg-open to use kde-open instead of gvfs-open?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, if it is the best solution, but the only way I found for now, is to edit the script `/usr/bin/xdg-open`.

What I've done is added one line, (cheking *$DESKTOP_SESSION* variable for *"kde-plasma"* value) to *detectDE()* function:

```
detectDE()
{
    if [ x"$KDE_FULL_SESSION" = x"true" ]; then DE=kde;
    elif [ x"$GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID" != x"" ]; then DE=gnome;
    elif `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.GetNameOwner string:org.gnome.SessionManager > /dev/null 2>&1` ; then DE=gnome;
    elif xprop -root _DT_SAVE_MODE 2> /dev/null | grep ' = \"xfce4\"$' >/dev/null 2>&1; then DE=xfce;
    elif [ x"$DESKTOP_SESSION" = x"LXDE" ]; then DE=lxde;
    ##########
    elif [ x"$DESKTOP_SESSION" = x"kde-plasma" ]; then DE=kde; #++ Added line +++
    ##########
    else DE=""
    fi
}
```

Comment: Not bad. Perhaps you should write an feature request or a bug report.